# Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 4 and head

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

here is my code, I find most site page document will raise this error, how to fix it?

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    xmlParseDoc("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                        "<html lang=\"en\">\n"
                        "<head>\n"
                        "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"> \n"
                        "</head>\n"
                        "<body>\n"
                        "\n"
                        "</body>\n"
                        "</html>");
    return (0);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your `meta` tag does not close.

```
"  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"> \n"
```

Should be

```
"  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/> \n"
```

Comment: Is there better way? I find most site(e.g. stackoverflow.com) <meta> not <meta/>

Comment: There are only 2 ways to close it. Either <meta /> or <meta> </meta>

Comment: But according to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp, html header mata should be like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlParseDoc instead of xmlParseDoc like following:

```
#include "libxml/HTMLparser.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    xmlDoc *d = htmlParseDoc("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                                     "<html lang=\"en\">\n"
                                     "<head>\n"
                                     "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"> \n"
                                     "</head>\n"
                                     "<body>\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "</body>\n"
                                     "</html>", "utf-8");
    return (0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Differences Between HTML and XHTML
In HTML the  tag has no end tag.

In XHTML the  tag must be properly closed.